# Rails preserve only 1 out of many records per day. Keep last, Delete rest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Rails 3.1, Ruby 1.9.2, AR/MySQL.

I am looking for suggestions on how to preserve only 1 result per time period (day) if the same type of result has many results during that period. An example might be tracking a stock price. Initially, we would save prices every 15 minutes, but would only require storage of every single price point for 1 week. After the first week, we would only require 1 price (last record, closing price) per day.

Here is a simple first try that does work, but is terribly inefficient:

```
# stock has many prices, price has one stock
# get all prices for single stock older than 1 week
prices = stock.prices.where("created_at < ? ", Time.now-1.week)  
prices.group_by{ |price| price.created_at.to_date }.each do |k,v| # group by day
  if v.count > 1  # if many price points that day
    (v[0]..v[v.size-2]).each {|r| r.delete} # delete all but last record in day
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions. I will try to update as I work through it in hopes it will help somebody down the line.

Answer (score 3):

You can make it much more efficient by doing it all in SQL, and by limiting the range to the last time this was run. Also, if you add a column to mark the older end-of-day entries as "archived", then it makes the queries a lot simpler. An archived price is one that you will not delete after a week.

```
rails generate migration add_archived_to_prices archived:boolean
```

Before migrating, modify the migration to index on the created_at column.

```
class AddArchivedToPrices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :prices, :archived, :boolean
    add_index :prices, :created_at
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :prices, :created_at
    remove_column :prices, :archived
  end
end
```

The workflow would go something like this:

```
# Find the last entry for each day for each stock using SQL (more efficient than finding these in Ruby)
keepers =
  Price.group('stock_id, DATE(created_at)').
        having('created_at = MAX(created_at)').
        select(:id).
        where('created_at > ?', last_run) # Keep track of the last run time to speed up subsequent runs

# Mark them as archived
Price.where('id IN (?)', keepers.map(&:id)).update_all(:archived => true)

# Delete everything but archived prices that are older than a week
Price.where('archived != ?', true).
      where('created_at < ?", Time.now - 1.week).
      where('created_at > ?', last_run). # Keep track of the last run time to speed up subsequent runs
      delete_all
```

As a final note, be sure not to combine `group()` and `update_all()`. `group()` gets ignored with `update_all()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling delete on each like

```
 (v[0]..v[v.size-2]).each {|r| r.delete}
```

Do delete_all but not the last ones

```
price_ids_to_keep = []
if v.count > 1  # if many price points that day
  price_ids_to_keep << v[-1].id # get the last
else
  price_ids_to_keep << v[0].id
end

prices.where('id not in (?)',price_ids_to_keep).delete_all
```

I have never done this but I'm pretty sure it should work

---

This is better since it will make less DELETE queries, but there should be a way to make all this in just one big query

---

With a business eyes, you or your team should think better about that. Storage is cheap nowadays and information like this can be precious for future data mining and stuff like that.